# asp.net formview inside gridview row

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, formview

I need a gridview such that when I click on a row to edit it, the data shows in a formview within that row. The user can then make updates within the formview. I am not able to find a suitable example that can do something like this. Can somebody please point me to an appropriate example that does this.

Note that I am using ASP.NET.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from Kendo , You can download and use their tools for free with limited support.

[Kendo Inline Editing Grid for ASP.Net](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-inline.html)